# Can anyone interpret verbose shutdown messages?

Tags: macos, shutdown

I almost always boot up in Verbose mode so I can see what's happening during boot up/shut down. Usually critical errors make themselves obvious, some lesser errors aren't so obvious but can be cleared up, and yet other errors aren't really errors at all and should be expected. I've fixed a bunch of things on startup, and now I'm trying to figure out messages I see on shutdown.

I'm basically just wondering if anyone can be an interpreter and tell me if any of this is bad or should not be happening, or if it all just looks normal.

Sorry for posting these messages as a photo. I'm not sure where to find a text log, if there is one:

[image]

It looks like there are a lot of processes that are staying alive until the system finally gives up on them and kills them all. If this is to be expected, that would be helpful to know. If not, how can I make the shut down run more smoothly?

Oh, and can anyone explain the anonymous.sudo processes? Is that okay? Where might that come from?

Thanks for any illumination you can offer!

Comment: Log files are in `/var/log`

Comment: You can use Console.app to look at the log files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on each executable.

The closedown process sends a signal SIGTERM to each process and the process should then cleanup and shut itself down. This includes subprocesses and that appears to be most of the lines in your log - perhaps the parent does not shut its subprocesses down when it does, also see Unix zombie processes in [wikipaedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zombie_process)

I would suggest that the original parent has not behaved 'properly' but probably does not matter unless there become many more zombie processes when the OS could run out of process handles.

Comment: So how might I find the parent process? How might I make it "behave?" How many zombies are too many? Is the answer just that none of these errors matter and I can ignore them? ...an answer I would be fine with.

Comment: You cannot always find the parent as it might be killed off, to fix it look at the source code of the app, there is a fixed number of processes ands threads but depends on OS e.g. http://support.apple.com/kb/HT3854 and  you can ignore them but I would be wary of an app that left many zombies as what else does it do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Interpreting error messages is not far removed from reading tea leaves. Having said that, I would start by uninstalling (or at least updating) your copy of TaoEffect Espionage. It looks like it installs a driver of some sort which is failing to quit.

Comment: You think all of this is due to Espionage? I suppose I could change to a different solution for encrypted folders if that would solve the whole thing. I can't give up privacy/security, but I don't have to use Espionage to get it. Espionage was just included in a bundle, so I had it before I knew I would need it and have used it ever since. :D